# Google Sheets If else formula

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

[image]

I'm trying to write an if else statement in Google Sheets.
I want the value in cell `B2` to dictate what the value you will be in cell `D2`.  If the cell `B2` is less than 12 than I want `D2 = 17`, if `B2` is less than 15 but greater than 12 then I want it to equal to 16 and so on and so forth as shown by the code above.

Comment: Any additional feedback for the answers already given?

Answer (score 1):

Do I have to use AND?

Yes.
The formula to use would be:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking could be `IF` or `IFS`.

The syntax is for `IF` is

```
IF(logical_expression,value_if_true,value_if_false)
```

The syntax for `IFS` is

```
IFS(condition1, value1, [condition2, value2, …])
```

Reference

- [IF function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en)
- [IFS function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7014145?hl=en)

Comment: IFS worked.  =IFS(B2<12, 17, 12<B2<15, 16, 15<B2<19, 15, 19<B2<22, 14, 22<B2, 13) . Thank you

Comment: @the_wac Thanks for confirming. Please accept the answer. Ref. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: actually 12<B2<15, 16, 15<B2<19, 15, 19<B2<22, 14, none of those statements work.  Its apparently not the proper format.  Do I have to use AND?

Comment: I'm sorry, it's not clear to me what you mean. Please create a new question including some sample input data, the expected results, the formula that you tried and the result that you got.